# IF Year(today) is x years greater than Year(A1) Then

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am struggling to get this formula working.

If the current year minus the year in A1 is greater than 50 years, then yes, otherwise no

`=IF((YEAR(TODAY)-YEAR(F13)>50), yes, no)`

Comment: Try: `=IF(YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(A1)>50,"Yes","No")`

Comment: I was initially receiving a NAME error with my formula. Now it is resolved, however the result is always yes, regardless if the the year in A1 is less than 50 years ago.

Comment: Then your data is not correct since there is nothing wrong with the suggested formula.

Comment: I am not sure why though. Regardless of the year I enter in A1, the result is always the same. This is with the formula in your comment copy and pasted.

Comment: Sounds like you are not actually inputting an actual date in `A1` but rather an integer which represents a year.

Comment: Oh....yes you are right. I have now entered a custom format of yyyy, however it requires I enter a date formatted as dd/mm/yyyy instead. Is it possible to enter just a whole year?

Comment: Sure remove the 2nd nested year from the suggested formula and just refer to `A1`

Comment: Thats it! Thanks alot